# UISplitViewController not showing right view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller

I am making my app for 3.2 but I recently started trying the new SDK 4.2beta2 and my app does not shows the right view. Is just black.

I checked and the splitViewController is indeed loading the right controller and the object is on memory but is not shown. I wonder if someone has experienced the same problem and/or where to start looking at since everything seems to be fine.

Thanks in advance

Ignacio.

Comment: I think this is a bug of iOS4.2beta